# Time Series Forecast - Evaluating accuracy

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, model-evaluation

I am very new to R and the forecast package authored by Rob Hyndman.
I am working on a time series with 24 samples per hour. I trained a random forest regressor to forecast 6 hour ahead values and am using MAPE(Mean Absolute Percentage Error) on a held out duration as the accuracy metric.

I want to compare its accuracy with standard time series methods like ARMA and ARIMA models.

Time Series Sample

[image]

Here is what I have currently. [data.csv](https://gist.github.com/sivapvarma/aa277c81f7a617b1f584d0ea32856eb4) has 576*16(16 days worth) samples and I wish to measure forecast accuracy on last 3 days.

```
library(forecast)
pv_data = read.csv("data.csv", header=FALSE)
pv_ts <- ts(pv_data$V2)
train_ts <- window(pv_ts, end=576*13)
test_ts <- window(pv_ts, start=576*13+1)
fit <- auto.arima(train_ts)
accuracy(forecast(fit, h=576*3), test_ts)
```

This gives me MAPE  which is average of `h = 1 to 576*3` samples ahead point forecast absolute errors.

**Question:** How to find the average of `h=144` ahead forecast absolute percent error of the estimates of samples in `test_ts`? Specifically, how to calculate $ \frac {\sum\limits_{T=576*13-h}^{576*16-h} \left\lvert \tfrac{\hat{e}_{T+h}}{y_{T+h}}\right\rvert }{576*3}$ with `h=144` where  $\hat{e}_{T+h}=\hat{y}_{T+h | T}-y_{T+h}$?

Comment: Post the data...

Comment: @TomReilly Created a gist. Please see the update.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RichardHardy updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here. The forecast at `h=144` is just a point estimate whereas the MAPE is a measure of average accuracy over a selection of point forecasts.

As in your case, the sequence of point forcasts from `h=1` to `h=576*3`is used to calculate the MAPE in your current example. If you want to evaluate the accuracy of your 6-hour ahead forecast, why not just look at the forecast error? I.e. $\hat{e}_{T+h}=\hat{y}_{T+h | T}-y_{T+h}$

EDIT: Added a rough outline to a solution of what I think is your problem. You mention calculating the "average" for `h=144` but the average is equal to the point estimate because you only have one forecast at this particular horizon.

```
library(forecast)
pv_data = read.csv("data.csv", header=FALSE)
pv_ts <- ts(pv_data$V2)
train_ts <- window(pv_ts, end=576*13)
test_ts <- window(pv_ts, start=576*13+1)
fit <- auto.arima(train_ts)

#Store point forecasts
fc <- forecast(fit, h=576*3)$mean

# Store actual outcome
y <- window(pv_ts, start=576*13+144, end=576*13+144)

# Store point forecast for h=144
y_hat <- fc[144]

# Calculate ape at h=144
ape <- abs((y_hat-y)/y)
```

Comment: I want to average `h=144` ahead forecast absolute percent error of the estimates of samples in `test_ts`. Specifically calculate $ \frac {\sum\limits_{T=576*13-h}^{576*16-h} APE(\hat{e}_{T+h})}{576*3}$ with `h=144`. I am not sure how to do that cleanly in R.

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear. Please take a look.

Comment: So you want to calculate the MAPE from  `h=1` to `h=144` ? Or do you want to calculate $\left|\frac{(\hat{y}_{T+144 | T}-y_{T+144})}{y_{T+144}}\right|$? I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to calculate MAPE only for `h=144` which is the average of $\left|\frac{(\hat{y}_{T+144 | T}-y_{T+144})}{y_{T+144}}\right|$

Comment: Updated answer to what I think you want to do. However, like I mention, calculating the average of $\left|\frac{(\hat{y}_{T+144 | T}-y_{T+144})}{y_{T+144}}\right|$ doesn't make any sense because this is just one number.

Comment: Once we fit an ARIMA model, we get the coefficients and the number of times to difference. Using these we can get 144 steps ahead forecasts for all samples in test_ts. For example use only true samples till T=576*13-144 to get a estimate(forecast) for T=576*13 sample. Use true samples till T=576*13-143 to get an estimate for T=576*13+1 sample and so on. Once we have such h=144 steps ahead forecast estimates for all samples in test_ts using coefficients of our arima model, I want to calculate the MAPE of those estimates. I think the equation in the question matches my description here.

Comment: Okay, so what you really want to do is "rolling/recursive window estimation" and calculate the MAPE for the sequence of `h=144`forecasts from the different windows? This is significantly more complicated and probably more suited for stack overflow. I can point you to a [function](https://github.com/MathiasModin/Econometrics/blob/master/RollingWindow.R) I have written for this purpose. Have a look at the function `r.arima()` in there. It might do what you want. Let me know if you want a brief explanation of how it works.